# Image to imageView from Path vs List Collection?

Tags: java, android, xamarin, android-image

I am trying to find Which is the best way to load images to imageview inside a recyclerview adapter or a a view pager? 
1) To load images from a path inside the OnBindViewHolder? 
2) To load images inside a List Collection and then to show them up?
Example for method 2:

```
public class myImages
{
  public byte image {get; set;}
}

List<myImages> mItems= new List<myImages>();
mItems.Add(new myImages{image = "Here i am load my image"});
```

Is this a good practice? which from two ways are better?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research,If you have massive data to load images from a path inside the OnBindViewHolder is prefer. when `recyclerview` need show it, then load it.

There are two ways to Optimize `recyclerview`

1.You also could override `onScrollStateChanged` method, Images that are not loaded when swiping are not loaded immediately, and will only load when the slide stops.

2.Control thread count:add a thread pool to load these data.

If you did not have massive data, load all images in local to inside a List Collection and then to show them up.

Comment: Are there any updates for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please try to mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.